# How do you show an $m$-simplex is homeomorphic to a cone?

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Show that, for $0 \le i \le m$,  $[p_0, ..., p_m]$ is homeomorphic to the cone $C[p_0, ..., \bar p_i, ..., p_m]$ with vertex $p_i$, where $\bar p_i$ means delete $p_i$.

It absolutely makes sense intuitively: $C[p_0, ..., \bar p_i, ..., p_m]$ is just $[p_0, ..., p_m]$ with a point taken out and then creating a new point via. the vertex which can be deformed to be homeomorphic to $[p_0, ..., p_m]$.

But I'm a little confused as to how to show this analytically through a homeomorphism.
Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You haven't stated your definition of the simplex $[p_0,\ldots,p_m]$, but I'll use the standard $$[p_0,\ldots,p_m] = \left\{ \sum_k a_k p_k : \sum_k a_k = 1 \text{ and } a_k \geq 0\right\}.$$

Recall that the cone on a space $X$ is $CX = X \times I/X \times 1$. Define a map $$[p_0,\ldots,p_m] \to C[p_0,\ldots,\overline{p_i},\ldots,p_m], \quad \sum_k a_kp_k\mapsto \begin{cases}\displaystyle\left(\sum_{k \neq i} \frac{a_k}{1-a_i}p_k,a_i\right) & \text{ if } a_i \neq 1 \\ (p_i,1) & \text{ if } a_i = 1\end{cases}.$$

Intuitively, this map "stretches out" each layer $\{ \sum_k a_kp_k  : a_i = c\}$ onto the corresponding cone layer $[p_0,\ldots,\overline{p_i},\ldots,p_m] \times c$ for all $c \in [0,1)$ and maps the tip $p_i$ of the simplex to the tip of the cone. Continuity of this map is rather clear except perhaps at the special tip $p_i$ of the simplex. But note that images of sets of the form $$[p_0,\ldots,\overline{p_i},\ldots,p_m] \times (1-\epsilon,1] \subset [p_0,\ldots,\overline{p_i},\ldots,p_m] \times I,$$ $\epsilon > 0$, form a neighborhood basis around the tip of the cone. And the preimage by our map of any such neighborhood is just $\{ \sum_k a_kp_k  : a_i > 1 - \epsilon\} \subset [p_0,\ldots,p_m]$, which is a neighborhood of the tip $p_i$ of the simplex.

Finally, it is easy to see that our map is a bijection (each layer $\{ \sum_k a_kp_k  : a_i = c\}$ of our simplex corresponds bijectively to the layer $[p_0,\ldots,\overline{p_i},\ldots,p_m] \times c$ of the cone). As the simplex is compact and the cone is Hausdorff, our map is a homeomorphism.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how $f$ (your function) is continuous? I don't see how an arbitrary $f^{−1}(U)$ (not necessarily containing the point) is open in $M=[p_1,…,p_n]$ for $U$ in the topology of the cone. Particularly where you say "continuity of this map is rather clear", can you show explicitly how its continuous?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where the continuity of the map is more obvious. Let's prove $C[p_0, \dots, p_{m - 1}] \cong [p_0, \dots, p_m]$. Define a map $f : [p_0, \dots, p_{m - 1}] \times I \to [p_0, \dots, p_m]$ given by
$$
f\left(\sum_{i = 0}^{m - 1} t_ip_i, s\right)
= (1 - s)\sum_{i = 0}^{m - 1} t_ip_i + sp_m.
$$
This is well-defined since the coefficients $(1 - s)t_0, \dots, (1 - s)t_{m - 1}, s$ sum to $1$, and it is clearly continuous. Observe that $f$ sends all points whose second coordinate is $1$ to $p_m$, so by the universal property of quotients, $f$ descends to a continuous map $\tilde{f} : C[p_0, \dots, p_{m - 1}] \to [p_0, \dots, p_m]$.

We claim that $\tilde{f}$ is a bijection. To do this, you can show that the map in the other answer is an inverse. It's also not difficult to directly show that $\tilde{f}$ is injective and surjective.

Finally, use the fact that $C[p_0, \dots, p_{m - 1}]$ is compact and Hausdorff to conclude that $\tilde{f}$ is a homeomorphism.

Here are a few general tips. First, whenever you want to find a map from a quotient space $X / \sim$ to another space $Y$, you should almost always first define a continuous map $X \to Y$, and then show that it descends to a (necessarily continuous) map $X / {\sim} \to Y$. This is because it is usually easier to prove directly that the map $X \to Y$ is continuous, rather than trying to fumble around with the quotient topology to prove $X / {\sim} \to Y$ is continuous. Second, whenever you want to show that a space is homeomorphic to a quotient space, it is often easier to define a homeomorphism from the quotient space to the other space since you can use the previous remark to prove continuity easily. In this case, you saw that it is easier to justify continuity of the map $C[p_0, \dots, p_{m - 1}] \to [p_0, \dots, p_m]$ rather than the map $[p_0, \dots, p_m] \to C[p_0, \dots, p_{m - 1}]$.